# R application not showing ggmap

Tags: r, shiny, ggmap, shiny-server

I am plotting ggmap in R app, my serv.R file

```
mapImageData1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -0.016179, lat = 51.538525),
                             color = "color",
                             source = "google",
                             maptype = "satellite",
                             zoom = 17)

    p<-ggmap(mapImageData1,
          extent = "device",
          ylab = "Latitude",
          xlab = "Longitude")
    print(p)
```

Following error shows on UI

```
Error:cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.538525,-0.016179&zoom=17&size=%20640x640&scale=%202&maptype=satellite&sensor=false'
```

And in Application folder 'ggmapTemp.png' is generating but it is 0 byte.

Also in log it shows :

```
Warning in download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
  unable to connect to 'maps.googleapis.com' on port 80.
Error in download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.538525,-0.016179&zoom=17&size=%20640x640&scale=%202&maptype=satellite&sensor=false'
```

I have checked internet working through r console.
any one has any idea

Thanks in advance..